Computing Component of Vector Outside Convex Hull of Set of Vectors
I have a set of points ${x_n}_{n=1}^N$ where $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I have another vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I'd like to efficiently compute the component of $y$ that lives outside the convex hull of the set of points ${x_n}$.
Is this possible, and if so, what algorithms/methods exists for doing so?
To be clear, I do not want to know whether the vector $y$ is inside or outside the convex hull. I want to compute the component of $y$ outside the convex hull. The result should be a vector, not a Boolean.
In case it is helpful, in my setting, $N >> D$.
Related Prior Questions:

What's an efficient way to find if a point lies in the convex hull of a point cloud?
Rough test if points are inside/outside of convex hull

